# wp_enqueue_script() not working at all

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to enqueue JavaScript files using `wp_enqueue_script()`, but it isn't working at all. Here is my code:

```
function load_css_js()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('gdgt-base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/gdgt-base.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('gdgt-icon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/icons/css/gdgt.css', true);
    wp_register_script('gdgt-base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gdgt-base.js', array(
        'jquery'
    ) , true);
    wp_enqueue_script('gdgt-base');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css_js')
```

However, when I deregister the default WP Javasciprt and register jquery from somewhere else, it works. What may cause this problem? Thanks for the help!